# General view of Theorems

Tags: logic, proof-theory, meta-math

I'm trying to see *almost* all theorems ( at least the non-existential ones ) as affirming that some formula ( mostly of first-order logic language ) is a logical consequence of other formulas.

So, given a Theorem, if its hypothesis are $A_i$ and it's conclusion is $C$, it would be affirming that  :
        $$\left\{  {A_1 ,A_2 , A_3,..,A_n}  \right\}    \models    C$$

Then by **Deduction Theorem**, this is the same as affirming that the following formula is **logically valid**.
      $$A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge  A_3 \wedge ... \wedge A_n    \to         C$$

But to say that that formula is logically valid, is the same as saying that, for example, the following also is :

$$A_3  \to ( A_1 \wedge  A_2 \wedge A_4 \wedge ... \wedge A_n    \to         C )$$

Or that the following ( reduction ad absurdum ) is logically valid ....
      $$[\neg (A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge  A_3 \wedge ... \wedge A_n    \to         C) \to B    ]  \wedge [ \neg (A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge  A_3 \wedge ... \wedge A_n    \to         C) \to \neg B ]   \to  (A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge  A_3 \wedge ... \wedge A_n    \to         C)  $$

Or that for example, the following formula is logically valid ( by doing some equivalences and using contrapositive ).
      $$(A_1 \wedge \neg C \wedge  A_3 \wedge A_4)    \to   ( A_5 \wedge .... \wedge  A_n \wedge      A_2) $$

Which would be affirming that :
     $$  \left\{  {A_1,\neg C , A_3,  A_4 } \right\}  \models   ( A_5 \wedge .... \wedge  A_n \wedge      A_2) $$

Which could be thought as a new theorem. And the previous formulas could also thought as representing some theorem.

And the list could go on, providing logically equivalent formulas, by using the axiom schemmas of propositional logic, equality and first-order-logic.

So i have two questions :

1 - Is this to say that actually each one of those logically equivalent formuals represents a theorem that is equivalent to the theorem represented by our initial formula ?  Is this to say that actually a theorem represents a bunch of equivalent theorems and we can choose to prove any representative of that "Theorem Equivalence class" , and by proving that we will have proved all our other representatives, including our initial representative of the theorem  ( that were given in the problem or that were written initially )   ?

2 - Now, if the first question has a positive answer. The most important question ( for me ): If have a proof of some representative of some "Theorem Equivalence class" ( as i'm calling the set of all theorems represented by formulas that are logically equivalent to one another ) , are we sure that there exists a proof of each representative of that "Theorem Equivalence class" ?  I think ( but i'm not sure ) that this is the same as asking, that if a theorem can be proved by a specific method ( supppose some direct proof ), are we 100% sure it can be proven by all other valid methods ( all other direct proofs, proof by contradiction, etc,etc ) ?

As an **example**, our Theorem is :

$$ \text{Suppose }  a,b \text{ and } c \text{ are real numbers and  } a>b. \text{ If } ac \leq  bc \text{ then }  c \leq0 .$$

I'm interpreting this theorem as affirming that  :
 $$ \left\{ "\text{a,b,c are real numbers, "a>b"}" \right\}   \models (ac \leq  bc   \to    c\leq 0   ) $$

Then by deduction-theorem, exportation and contrapositive, we could reach the following formula :
$$ \left\{ "c > 0 ", (ac \leq  bc ), "a>b" \right\}   \models \text{ "a,b,c are not real numbers" }   $$

Which could be thought as representing the following theorem :
$$ \text{Suppose }  c>0 \text{ ,} ac \leq bc.\text{ If  a>b, then a,b or c are not real numbers} $$

Now, since we are able to prove the initial theorem ( by doing contrapositive on the last two formulas  ) does this means that we could also prove the theorem whose conclusion is a,b,c are not real numbers and also all others possibly obtained by logical equivalences ?

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Your particular example is problematic, as throwing in complex numbers to $\mathbb R$ makes $<$ no longer well defined. But in general, yes, it does seems like there are myriad re-spellings of a particular theorem that are all potentially interesting, but indeed everything you can know is contained in the original statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 2)*

If I understand well your example, from :

> $[(\mathbb R(a) \land \mathbb R(b) \land \mathbb R(c)) \land (a > b)] \rightarrow [(ac \le bc) \rightarrow (c \le 0)]$

through the *tautology* : $[(A \land B) \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D)] \leftrightarrow [(\lnot D \land B \land C) \rightarrow \lnot A]$

we can derive :

> $[(c > 0)  \land (a > b) \land (ac \le bc)] \rightarrow \lnot (\mathbb R(a) \land \mathbb R(b) \land \mathbb R(c))$.

*Note*. Please, be careful with the "reading" of the consequent : it says that *one of* $a,b,c$ is **not** a real number.

Of course, all the "intermediate" transformation licensed by logical rules are all theorems of your theory.

*Question 1)*

Let $A$ the above formula; saying that it is a theorem of a theory $T$ means that there is a set $\Gamma$ of non-logical axioms [the *axioms* of $T$], such that :

$\Gamma \vdash A$.

Now, if $A'$ is an "equivalent" transformation of $A$, i.e.if $\vdash A \leftrightarrow A'$, then simply with *modus ponens* we have that :

> if $\Gamma \vdash A$, then $\Gamma \vdash A'$.

*Added*

We can "systhematize" this issue referring to Joseph Shoenfield, *Mathematical Logic* (1967), page 33 :

> **Deduction Theorem**. Let $A$ be a *closed* formula in $T$. For every formula $B$ of $T$, $\vdash_T A \rightarrow B$ iff $B$ is a theorem of $T \cup \{ A \}$.

This is the fact we already know.

See also page 41 :

> The primary object of a formal system is to provide a framework for proving theorems. Hence a particularly important problem for any formal system $\mathcal F$ is: find a necessary and sufficient condition that a formula of $\mathcal F$ be a theorem of $\mathcal F$.
>
> This is called the *characterization problem* for $\mathcal F$. [...] There is a trivial solution to the characterization problem for a theory $T$: a formula is a theorem iff it has a preof.
>
> Clearly whether or not $A$ is a theorem of $T$ depends strongly on what the nonlogical axioms of $T$ are. Hence we must expect the condition for $A$ to be a theorem of $T$ to refer not only to $A$, but also to the nonlogical axioms of $T$.

Page 42 :

> If $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas in the theory $T$, then $T \cup \Gamma$ is the theory obtained from $T$ by adding all of the formulas in $\Gamma$ as new nonlogical axioms.
>
> **Reduction Theorem**. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of formulas in the theory $T$, and let $A$ 
>   be a formula of $T$. Then $A$ is a theorem of $T \cup \Gamma$ iff there is a theorem of $T$ 
>   of the form $B_1 \rightarrow ( ... \rightarrow ( B_n \rightarrow A)...)$, where each $B_i$ is the closure of a formula in $\Gamma$ [obviously, the proof make use of the *Deduction Th*].
>
> The reduction theorem reduces the characterization problem for $T \cup \Gamma$ to that 
>   for $T$. Now any theory $T'$ is $T \cup \Gamma$, where $T$ is obtained from $T'$ by omitting all nonlogical axioms and $\Gamma$ is the set of nonlogical axioms of $T'$.
>
> Hence to solve the characterization problem for all theories, it suffices to solve it for theories with no nonlogical axioms.

For simplicity, we can use the example [page 22] regarding the :

> *elementary theory of groups*, designated by $G$. The only non-logical symbol of $G$ is the binary function symbol $\circ$. The nonlogical axioms of $G$ are:
>
> **$G_1$**. $\forall x \forall y \forall z [(x \circ y) \circ z = x \circ (y \circ z)]$
>
> **$G_2$**. $\exists x[\forall y(x \circ y = y) \land \forall y \exists z(z \circ y = x )]$.
>
> By a model of a theory $T$, we mean a structure for $L(T)$ [the *language* of the theory] in which all the non-logical axioms of $T$ are *true*.
>
> A formula is true in $T$ if it is true in every model of $T$; equivalently, if it is a logical consequence of the nonlogical axioms of $T$.

In conclusion a theorem of *group theory* is a formula $A$ such that :

> > $\Gamma = \{ G_1, G_2 \} \vdash A$.

$A$ is *true* in every model of $\Gamma$, i.e.in every *structure* which satisfy the *group axioms*.

This fact does **not** imply that $A$ is logically (or universally) *valid*, i.e.true in every structure.

But, by the above results :

> $G_1 \land G_2 \rightarrow A$

**is** *valid*.

Comment: I'm on a confusion here, i was thinking that we could use the word Theorem withouth needing to talk about a theory, for example i was considering a theorem to be any affirmation in the form of an implication ( A1,A2,..,An |= C ), regardless of being theorem of a theory or not ... Should Theorems of Mathematics be always viewed as coming from a theory ? Even basic ones like the one i mentioned in question, or this one ( x>3 and y<2  -> x² - 2y < 5 )  , or this one ( If n is is even then n² is even ) ? Which theories would they come from ?

Comment: @nerdy - there is **no** contradiction. A theorem $A$ is **always** a theorem of a theory $T$, i.e.proved from a set $\Gamma$ of *axioms*. When $\Gamma = \emptyset$ we have the theorems of (first-order) logic, i.e.the (universally) *valid* formulae. We call so, because they are *true* in every model; thus, we have that they are theorems of every theory. A theorem of e.g *calculus* of course needs axioms to be proved: axioms regarding *real numbers*. If we have a theorem of *arithmetic*, like $\forall n (n \ge 0)$, we need the so-called (first-order) Peano's axioms in order to prove it.

Comment: Oh, i see.. should i consider "x>3 and y<2 -> x² - 2y < 5 "  or "n is is even then n² is even " as logically valid , then ?

Comment: @nerdy - of course no. *Valid* means true in **every** interpretation, not only true in the standard one. Consider $\forall n(n \ge0)$; it is obviously true if the domain of the interpretation is the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*, but not so if the domain is the set $\mathbb Z$ of *integers*.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, now the only main doubt i'm having is wether any theorem of mathematics is logically valid , or none of them are logically valid but only valid in certain models. The thing is that any theorem of Mathematics that involves an implication ( almost all ) it always seem that the conclusion is a logical consequence of the hypothesis, which would make the theorem logically valid ( true in all interpretations ). Even in "x>3 and y<2 ->   x² - 2y < 5 ", it can't think of an interpretation that would make the antecedent TRUE and the consequent false.Any idea ?

Comment: @nerdy - if $A$ is a theorem of a (first-order) mathematical theory and $\Gamma$ is the set of axioms of the mathematical theory, assuming for simplicity that $\Gamma$ is finite, i.e. $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, ... \gamma_n \}$, then $A$ is **not** logically valid, but $(\gamma_1 \land ... \land \gamma_n) \rightarrow A$ **is** logically valid.

Comment: OH, i see !!! That was the main problem, its just that all theorems of mathematics are expressed in the $\A -> C$ form, look for example Lagrange's Theorem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29 ), it is in the form A -> C , its not just C.Actually almost all theorems of mathematics is in A -> C.    So actually all theorems of mathematics are logically valid and theorems of logic, but people insist on calling  Lagrange's Theorem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29 ) a theorem of Group Theory, that would be only the formula C.

Comment: About your example, I think we need x² - 2y > 5 ---

Comment: You are absolute right, thanks again for solving this doubt i'm carrying for so long.

Comment: @nerdy - I've made some addition ... I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for adding.Just one thing, we read Lagrange's theorem as : "For any group G and H subgroup of G,  the order of H divides the order of G". I was thinking that this theorem would be on the form "G1,G2, definition_of_subgroup H"  |-  "Order of H divides order of G", being A =  "Order of H divides order of G" . Thats why i considered the whole theorem as logically valid.Am i right in considering the theorem on the form "G1,G2,definition" |- A .. or would the whole Lagrange Theorem would actually be on the form "A" ?

Comment: @nerdy - in this case, things are more complicated. The *group axioms* $G_1, G_2$ make reference to the elements $x,y,z$ of a group. Lagrange's Th express a property of every group. In f-o logic you cannot express property of *set* ob objects...

Comment: Would second-order logic would then suffice ?  It seems that almost every theorem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theorems )  follow this exact form that Lagrange's Theorem follow , expressing property of set of objects that were previous defined ( be it groups, ring-extensions, surfaces of revolution, set of trees, theories [ x is stronger than PA -> x is incomplete ] ) .Since almost every major Theorem is like this,I wonder why we talk about theorems of first-order theory and don't actually use second-order logic to express those major theorems.

Comment: I've found this reference : Alexander Prestel & Charles Delzell, *Mathematical Logic and Model Theory* (2011), page 49 : we have the f-o *group axioms* (as above), plus a fourt axiom for the *Abelian* property, plus the set $\{ G_{5,n} : n ≥ 1 \}$ of axioms expressing the *torsion free* property, plus the set $\{ G_{6,n} : n ≥ 1 \}$ expresses its *divisibility*. It has also axioms for *ordered, divisible, Abelian groups* and for *discrete ordered Abelian groups*.

Comment: @nerdy - 2nd order logic will do. But you can stay with f-o logic and use set-theory; quite all math theory are "reproducible" in set theory. Thus, the basic properties of *groups* will be theorem of (say) $\mathsf {ZFC}$. Thus, in principle, for every thoerem $Th_G$ of *group theory* we have  $\mathsf {ZFC} \vdash Th_G$. The only problem is that  $\mathsf {ZFC}$ is not *finitely axiomatizable*. Thus we have to move to  $\mathsf {NBG}$, which is. In the end if $BigAx$ is the conjunction of the (finite) list of axioms of $\mathsf {NBG}$, we can say: $\vdash  BigAx \rightarrow Th_G$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, i forgot we can translate everything to set-theory.It's so wierd then that we talk about Lagrange Theorem being a theorem of Group Theory instead of it being a theorem of set theory, if the language of group theory can't even cover the major theorems of group theory.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this to say that actually each one of those logically equivalent formuals represents a theorem that is equivalent to the theorem represented by our initial formula ?"

All theorems are logically equivalent anytime you have a you have the formulas [(p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)] and {(p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$[(q$\rightarrow$p)$\rightarrow$(p=q)]} as axioms or theorems ("theses" hereafter... "=" indicates logical equivalence, I've also assumed uniform substitution and detachment here).  If you have a deduction meta-theorem (which oftentimes doesn't say anything about conjunctions), then you have [(p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)] as a thesis.  And we do have {(p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$[(q$\rightarrow$p)$\rightarrow$(p=q)]} for what you've referenced.  So, the answer to your question is "yes".

That doesn't imply though that each thesis has the same power in that you can derive the same consequences solely from some thesis T as you can from thesis S under the same rule (because you might not have the ability to derive [(p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)] or {(p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$[(q$\rightarrow$p)$\rightarrow$(p=q)]}).

"Now, if the first question has a positive answer. The most important question ( for me ): If have a proof of some representative of some "Theorem Equivalence class" ( as i'm calling the set of all theorems represented by formulas that are logically equivalent to one another ) , are we sure that there exists a proof of each representative of that "Theorem Equivalence class" ?"

If there cannot exist a proof of X, then there does not exist a theorem X.  If X does qualify as a theorem, then there can exist a proof X.  X comes as arbitrary here.  So, the answer to your question here is again "yes".

" I think ( but i'm not sure ) that is the same as asking, that if a theorem can be proved by a specific method ( supppose some direct proof ), are we 100% sure it can be proven by all other valid methods ( all other direct proofs, proof by contradiction, etc,etc ) ?"

This sounds different to me.  One might include axioms as part of the method.  It is not the case that if an axiom set under a set of rules of inference will enable you to prove a theorem, then any other axiom set under the same set of rules of inference will enable you to prove a theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the insight about equivalences, Dougt. Appreciated